# Compare differences before insert into oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Could you please tell me how to compare differences between table and my select query and insert those results in separate table? My plan is to create one base table (name RESULT) by using select statement and populate it with current result set. Then next day I would like to create procedure which will going to compare same select with RESULT table, and insert differences into another table called DIFFERENCES.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `RESULT_TABLE` using `CTAS` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE RESULT_TABLE
AS SELECT ... -- YOUR QUERY
```

Then you can use the following procedure which calculates the difference between your query and data from `RESULT_TABLE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIND_DIFF
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DIFFERENCES
  --data present in the query but not in RESULT_TABLE
  (SELECT ... -- YOUR QUERY
  MINUS
  SELECT * FROM RESULT_TABLE)
  UNION
  --data present in the RESULT_TABLE but not in the query
  (SELECT * FROM RESULT_TABLE
  MINUS
  SELECT ... );-- YOUR QUERY
  
END;
/
```

I have used the `UNION` and the difference between both of them in a different order using `MINUS` to insert the deleted data also in the `DIFFERENCES` table. If this is not the requirement then remove the query after/before the `UNION` according to your requirement.

Comment: My query has select, from, where, and clauses. Im trying to handle this by using differences now.

Comment: Yes, You need to replace `SELECT ...` with your entire query.

Comment: Ok, your query returns all data presented in RESULT table, but not in select statement. How to catch only results which are differ? I meant results which differ between those two selects?

Comment: MINUS operator compares all the mentioned columns from both the result/table and provides the data present in the first table/query and not present in the second query/table. It will not give all the data present in the RESULT.

Comment: You are right! Im so sorry i have put sysdate by accident. Thank you so much on this mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Create a table with results from the query, and ID as primary key
create table result_t as
   select id, col_1, col_2, col_3
     from <some-query>; 
    
-- Create a table with new rows, deleted rows or updated rows
create table differences_t as
   select id
       -- Old values
         ,b.col_1 as old_col_1         
         ,b.col_2 as old_col_2         
         ,b.col_3 as old_col_3
       -- New values
         ,a.col_1 as new_col_1         
         ,a.col_2 as new_col_2         
         ,a.col_3 as new_col_3
  -- Execute the query once again
     from <some-query> a
  -- Outer join to detect also detect new/deleted rows
     full join result_t  b using(id)
  -- Null aware comparison      
    where decode(a.col_1, b.col_1, 1, 0) = 0
       or decode(a.col_2, b.col_2, 1, 0) = 0
       or decode(a.col_3, b.col_3, 1, 0) = 0;
```